# How do I get a list of nodes in the currently active group?

Tags: python, node-editor

`context.space_data.node_tree.nodes` always returns a list of the nodes at the base level of the tree (not inside any group), even if the user is actually editing the nodes inside a group.

```
My Material  <-- context.spacedata.node_tree (always)
  └ Group
    └ Group in a group  <-- user is editing this
```

How can I get a list of the nodes in whatever group the user is busy with, no matter how far down the rabbit hole they've gone?

`context.active_node.id_data.nodes` is one solution, but it does not work if there is no active node (e.g. if the user just deleted it and hasn't selected anything since).

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be any obvious solution, so I've come up with a bit of a hack:

The trick is, `context.active_node` is always the actual active node in the tree the user is currently editing. `context.space_data.node_tree.nodes.active` (let's call it `tree_active` for short) is the active node for the base level (outside all groups). If the user is editing a group, `tree_active` will be a group node (because it was first selected+made active before the user hit Tab to edit it).

So if `context.active_node` is not the same as `tree_active`, then we know the user is inside a group. We don't know how deep they are though, so we need to recursively check if `tree_active` is the same as `context.active_node` - if it's not, then we use `tree_active`'s node tree as the new base tree we're checking against.

If we are in a group, `tree_active` will always be a group node (unless it is the same as `context.active_node`).

Here's the code I eventually came up with:

```
tree = context.space_data.node_tree  # Base level tree
if tree.nodes.active:
    while tree.nodes.active != context.active_node:
        # We are in a group, check next level
        tree = tree.nodes.active.node_tree
```

`tree` will be whatever node tree the user is currently editing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `edit_tree` instead of `node_tree` to get the tree currently being edited and access its `nodes` property for the list of nodes, e.g.:

```
context.space_data.edit_tree.nodes
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function will return current active node, or last active node the user was working with if Node Editor is not open:

```
def active_node(context):
    node_tree = context.scene.node_tree
    if node_tree and node_tree.nodes.active:
        while hasattr(node_tree.nodes.active, "node_tree"):
            node_tree = node_tree.nodes.active.node_tree
        return node_tree.nodes.active
```